# SSH login problem

Tags: ssh, vps

I have a VPS account and everytime I try to log in, I get a "password authentication failed, try again" message. I am double sure about my password and username so I couldn't possibly be wrong.

I am trying to login using the console provided inside solusvm and have even tried putty.

What could be the problem?

Comment: what host ? linnode gives you the lish option.

Comment: www.123systems.net/ is my host.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exact details...

1. Find out if your server has been activated.
2. Check you have the correct details: IP Address, username, password, URL to the control panel.
3. Did you receive an SSH key? This is rare, I have only experienced this once in an initial VPS setup.
4. If this is a managed server, perhaps sshd has been closed by administration.

Comment: Especially #1... In working with clients who are on shared hosting, I've found it to be *very* common for them to have to take some action (either through the admin panel or by contacting support) to enable ssh access.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth trying resetting your password - it can probably be done through your VPS vendor's website.

Comment: I have access to my vps account using solusvm control panel.I have all my passwords and also my java is in order,totally beats me on why it wont log me in.